# Does rollup support typescript in rollup config file?

Tags: typescript, rollup

It seems we can use typescript to write rollup config file. Say, I can create a file named `rollup.config.ts`, with content:

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';

export default {
  input: 'main.ts',
  plugins: [typescript()],
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs',
  },
  external: ['lodash']
}
```

It's working if I invoke rollup as `rollup -c rollup.config.ts`.

But if I use some typings in it:

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import {RollupFileOptions} from "rollup";

const config: RollupFileOptions = {
  input: 'main.ts',
  plugins: [typescript()],
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs',
  },
  external: ['lodash']
}

export default config;
```

It will report errors like:

```
$ rollup -c rollup.config.ts
[!] Error: Unexpected token
rollup.config.ts (4:12)
2: import {RollupFileOptions} from "rollup";
3: 
4: const config: RollupFileOptions = {
                 ^
```

Is it possible to make it work? I tried to use ts-node with

Comment: have you managed to find a solution? I am facing similar issues (cannot import another ts file)

Comment: @Moustachiste Still not yet, I have to use `rollup.config.js` for now

Comment: I saw this wasn't tracked on rollup's website so I opened an issue
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2879

Answer (score 39):

For the meantime, while it is not yet supported, JSDoc might be come useful to type check the rollup configuration. (It only works on editor that support JSDoc. e.g. VSCode).

```
/** @type {import('rollup').RollupOptions} */
const options = {
  ...
};

export default options;
```

Comment: tyck seems to not work properly tho. `const options = { output: { dir: 42 } };` `dir` needs to be a `string`, it's a `number`, but no error is shown in vscodium.

Comment: If you use multiple entry points don't forget to turn that as an array, e.g. `/** @type {import('rollup').RollupOptions[]} */`

Answer (score 30):

You can create your rollup configuration in TypeScript

```
import { RollupOptions } from "rollup";

const bundle: RollupOptions = {
//...
}
export default bundle
```

and use it with

```sh
rollup --config rollup.config.ts --configPlugin @rollup/plugin-typescript
```

You will need to add `rollup.config.ts` to the included files in your *tsconfig.json*.

```json
{
    "include": ["src/**/*", "rollup.config.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, including the rollup config file in tsconfig.json was what I was missing

Comment: This sounds so helpful but even with it in the `include` (and `@rollup/plugin-typescript` and `typescript` installed) I get the error: `Error: Cannot load plugin "@rollup/plugin-typescript": Cannot find package '@rollup/plugin-typescript' imported from <pathTo>/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/loadConfigFile.js.`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ah - my problem was actually a yarn workspaces / monorepo bug. Adding `nohoist` for `rollup` to my root `package.json` fixed it!

Comment: You can shorten it to `--configPlugin typescript`.

Comment: Adding `rollup.config.ts` fixed it for me, but I swear it was working before I had done this.

Comment: if you use the newer typescript2 plugin remember to use `--configPlugin typescript2`

Comment: i get error: [!] TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for D:\cli\rollup.config.ts

Answer (score 12):

You can create a separate `rollup.config.js` that looks like this:

```js
require('ts-node').register({
  compilerOptions: {
    module: 'CommonJS'
  },
  // and other tsconfig.json options as you like
});

module.exports = require('./rollup.config.ts');
```

You'll need to `npm install --save-dev ts-node` of course. Then run `npx rollup -c` and you're off to the races.

Answer (score 8):

With [Rollup v2.52.0](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/releases/tag/v2.52.0), you can specify a `--configPlugin` option as:

```
rollup --config rollup.config.ts --configPlugin typescript
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I still get the error `[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)`. Could you give an example?

Comment: For this to work you need `@rollup/plugin-typescript` and `typescript` installed as a dev dependency.

Answer (score 7):

it is actually possible, just import `defineConfig` from `rollup` and this will give your great IDE suggestions, for example:

```js
//rollup.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'rollup';

const rollupConfig = defineConfig({
  input: 'src/index.tsx',
  output: [
    {
      file: 'dist/bundle.cjs.js',
      format: 'cjs',
    },
  ],
});

export default rollupConfig;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's advised by the Rollup documentation too: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#config-intellisense

Comment: @JoséCabo the documentation also advises on how to do it with typescript via --configPlugin option.

Answer (score 1):

Rollup v3 TypeScript configuration

devDependencies

```
npm i -D typescript tslib @types/node rollup @rollup/plugin-typescript
```

```
import type { RollupOptions } from 'rollup';

const config: RollupOptions = {
    /* your config */
};
export default config;
```

```
"build": "rollup -c --configPlugin typescript"
```

If it is `rollup.config.ts` name can be omitted.

Remember to add `rollup.config.ts` in the `tsconfig.json` file, as I tripped up at this step.

```json
"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "rollup.config.ts"],
```

Rollup documentation

https://rollupjs.org/command-line-interface/#config-intellisense

Answer (score -3):

For the fastest compilation, go with this:

```
npm install sucrase -D
```

And in your `rollup.config.js`, do this:

```
require('sucrase/register')
module.exports = require('./rollup.config.ts')
```

https://github.com/alangpierce/sucrase